# Replace all text before a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
$(function(){
    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVEXYZ";
    var replaced = alphabet.replace(/(M).+$/,'');
    $('body').text(replaced);
});
```

How can I make this go in the opposite direction, replacing `M` and everything before it?

Comment: Your alphabet has no `W`, and two `E`s? ;)

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity It is rotated.

Comment: As soon as I read your comment I looked to see if the W and E keys were next to each other; sure enough.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `/^.+M/` expression:

```
$(function() {
    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVEXYZ";
    var replaced = alphabet.replace(/^.+M/,'');
    $('body').text(replaced);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kbZhU/1/

---

The faster option is to use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) methods:

```
$(function(){
    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVEXYZ";
    var replaced = alphabet.substring(alphabet.indexOf("M") + 1);
    $('body').text(replaced);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kbZhU/2/​

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method:

```
$(function(){
    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVEXYZ";
    var replaced = alphabet.split("M")[1];
    $('body').text(replaced);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI if you are trying to do this with more than one letter, you have to change it a bit.

Using @VisioN solution I was trying to replace anything in a URL up to a certain point.

So to get everything after 'google.com' in `https://www.google.com/analytics`, I had to do

```
const url = 'https://www.google.com/analytics'
const lookingFor = 'google.com'
const replaced = url.substring(url.indexOf(lookingFor) + lookingFor.length)
```

`replaced` will then return `/analytics`